# Seeking algorithm to invert (reverse? mirror? turn inside-out) a DAG

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm looking for an algorithm to "invert" (reverse? turn inside-out?) a
DAG:

```
       A*      # I can't ascii-art the arrows, so just
      / \      # pretend the slashes are all pointing
     B   C     # "down" (south-east or south-west)
    /   / \    # e.g. 
   G   E   D   # A -> (B -> G, C -> (E -> F, D -> F))
        \ /
         F
```

The representation I'm using is immutable truly a DAG (there are no
"parent" pointers).   I'd like to traverse the graph in some fashion
while building a "mirror image" graph with equivalent nodes, but with
the direction of relations between nodes inverted.

```
         F*
        / \
   G*  E   D   # F -> (E -> C -> A, D -> C -> A), G -> B -> A
    \   \ /    # 
     B   C     # Again, arrows point "down"
      \ /      # 
       A       #
```

So the input is a set of "roots" (here, {A}).  The output should be a
set of "roots" in the result graph: {G, F}. (By root I mean a node
with no incoming references. A leaf is a node with no outgoing
references.)

The roots of the input become the leaves of the output and visa
versa. The transformation should be an inverse of itself.

(For the curious, I'd like to add a feature to a library I'm using to
represent XML for structural querying by which I can map each node in
the first tree to its "mirror image" in the second tree (and back
again) to provide more navigational flexibility for my query rules.)

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't store the "parent" pointers? I'd imagine that would provide the invert operation for free, by doing depth-first search (or whatever) starting from the leaf node(s).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Traverse the graph building a set of reversed edges and a list of leaf nodes.

Perform a topological sort of the reversed edges using the leaf (which are now root) nodes to start with.

Construct the reversed graph based on the reversed edges starting from the end of the sorted list. As the nodes are constructed in reverse topological order, you are guaranteed to have constructed the children of a given node before constructing the node, so creating an immutable representation is possible.

This is either O(N) if you use structures for your intermediate representation which track all links in both directions associated with a node, or O(NlnN) if you use sorting to find all the links of a node. For small graphs, or languages which don't suffer from stack overflows, you can just construct the graph lazily rather than explicitly performing the topological sort. So it depends a little what you're implementing it all in how different this would be.

```
A -> (B -> G, C -> (E -> F, D -> F))

original roots: [ A ]
original links: [ AB, BG, AC, CE, EF, CD, DF ] 
reversed links: [ BA, GB, CA, EC, FE, DC, FD ]
reversed roots: [ G, F ]
reversed links: [ BA, CA, DC, EC, FE, FD, GB ] (in order of source)
topologically sorted: [ G, B, F, E, D, C, A ]
construction order : A, C->A, D->C, E->C, F->(D,E), B->A, G->B
```

Comment: Yes, this is basically what I spent the afternoon coding up except that I'm not actually explicitly doing a topological sort. I'm looping over the nodes picking those next whose children have already been mirrored. The effect is the same.

Comment: (It's a shame there's no clever recursive solution that doesn't require so many intermediate data structures.)

Answer (score 2):

Just do a depth-first search marking where you have already been, and each time you traverse an arrow you add the reverse to your result DAG. Add the leaves as roots.

Answer (score 2):

My intuitive suggestion would be to perform a Depth First traversal of your graph, and construct your mirrored graph simultaneously.

When traversing each node, create a new node in the mirrored graph, and create an edge between it and its predecessor in the new graph.

If at any point you reach a node which has no children, mark it as a root.

Comment: The difficult bit is that the nodes are *immutable* once created. so when I create a node i need to know all its children and they must be complete. I can't add stuff incrementally.

Comment: @bendin: During the DFS, you'll need to create a second DAG using a mutable datatype for nodes.  Afterwards, use a subsequent DFS over this new DAG to produce nodes of the desired immutable datatype.

Comment: Like j_random_hacker said, you'll probably need a mutable node type to serve as intermediate. In order to know all a nodes children during creation, you must know all of its parents in the original graph, the first time you see it. That could get a bit difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with a simple graph traversal. Keep in mind topological sorting will only be useful for directed acyclic graphs.

I used an adjacency list, but you can do a similar thing with an adjacency matrix.

In Python it looks like this:

```
# Basic Graph Structure
g = {}
g[vertex] = [v1, v2, v3] # Each vertex contains a lists of its edges
```

To find all the edges for v, you then traverse the list g[v] and that will give you all (v, u) edges.

To build the reversed graph make a new dictionary and build it something like this:

```
    reversed = {}
    for v in g:
        for e in g[v]:
            if e not in reversed:
                reversed[e] = []
            reversed[e].append(v)
```

This is very memory intensive for large graphs (doubling your memory usage), but it is a very easy way to work with them and quite quick. There may be more clever solutions out there involving building a generator and using a dfs algorithm of some sort, but I have not put a lot of thought into it.

Answer (score -1):

[Depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) might be able to generate what you're after: Note your path through the tree and each time you traverse add the reverse to the resulting DAG (leaves are roots).

Comment: How and why? You need to expand on this answer for it to be any use.

Comment: How does knowing how to perform a depth first search help solve this problem?

Comment: Quoting starblue:  "Marking where you have already been, and each time you traverse an arrow you add the reverse to your result DAG. Add the leaves as roots."