# Create a DAG given leaf nodes

Tags: algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

Assume we have a DAG with a single leaf Node `leafN`. Each node is an object containing list of parent nodes. Node class can be something like `class Node(Object, List[Node]`.

How to construct a DAG from `leafN`?

For e.g., given leaf node `leafD` with two parents, `leafD(Object@123, List(leafC(leafA(null)), leafB(leafA(null))))` it's DAG will be:

```
    leafA
   /     \
 leafB  leafC
    \    /
    leafD
```

i.e., `leafA(leafB(leafD(null)), leafC(leafD(null)))` (I am ignoring the objects from every node for clarity.)

In short we have a leaf node with parent pointers which themselves have parent pointers and finally, after applying an algorithm, we want a *root* node with pointers to children nodes which further have pointers to children nodes.

Code ain't required, algorithm or links to any will suffice.

Comment: What do you mean "create" do you mean to create a visualization of it?

Comment: @amit: No not a visualization. I want `leafA(leafB(leafD(null)), leafC(leafD(null)))` from `leafD(42, List(leafC(leafA(null)), leafB(leafA(null))))`. Ignore the ints from every node, those are the easy parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple, once you realise that notionally only the direction of the edges in the DAG has changed.

Instead of the `Parent ---> Child` node relationship, you have a `Child ---> Parent` relationship.

As such, all you need to do is construct a DAG from the given relationships, assuming that the Child node is actually the parent, and the parent nodes are childs.

So you end up with

```
    leafD
   ↙     ↘
 leafB  leafC
   ↘     ↙
    leafA
```

Now, all you need to do is reverse the edges in the DAG.

This is pretty simple, One way to do it would be to walk through the DAG, and get all the edge relationships, and then reverse them one by one.

Another would be to do this recursively using level order traversal.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/595029/1860929) for more solutions around how to reverse a DAG.

Comment: Woow, that was clean.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to put your nodes into some data structure that allows you to find a node easily. If your integer values in your node are sequential (or close to it) and start at a low number then you can use an array and just put the node with integer i in position i of the array (This makes including the integer in the node somewhat redundant).

This is all explained well on this site (but note that in their implementation the list is of the edges to, not the edges from) http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/42directed/

Comment: I modified the question to defocus on the actual values. They are objects not ints in my  case.

Comment: "their implementation the list is of the **edges to, not the edges from**)" ... that's the whole point, I have list of parents not children and want the other  way round finally.

Comment: Actually your new question confuses me. Do you want a function that has input the parent pointing nodes and outputs child pointing nodes?

Comment: Yes. Algorithm, function whatever.